# Using -1 instead of 0 in binary Restricted Boltzmann Machines

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, binary-data, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am aware of the fact that binary Restricted Boltzmann Machines - which use $0$ or $1$ as states - are asymmetric, in the sense that two states have to be both $1$ for $w_{ij}$ to enter in the energy expression. This is discussed in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61594/boltzmann-machines-and-the-asymmetry-between-0-and-1), for example. I also know that the solution to this problem is the so called *centering trick*, in which we remove an offset from the data (which usually is the mean). 
However I still wonder why we do not use $-1$ instead of $0$, and I'm not able to find any explanation. Can someone explain me why the "spin" binary units $\{-1,+1\}$ are not used? 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, did you find a reasonable argument for this? As you mention, in any case the centering trick makes the training invariant to these choices.